# how to sort 2d array php from sql inserted

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sorting

This is my inseted sql to array

```
$e=0;
while ($row45 = mysqli_fetch_array($res1)) {
                $proIdArr0["id"][$e]=$row45['proId'];
                $proIdArr0["qty"][$e]=$row45["proQty"];
                $e++;
            }
print_r($proIdArr0);
```

And it prints

```
Array ( 
[id] => Array ( 
    [0] => 15
    [1] => 13
    [2] => 16 ) 

[qty] => Array ( 
    [0] => 54
    [1] => 84
    [2] => 54 ) 
)
```

and i want to sorted by the id so it will be for example this output

```
id | qty
-------
13 | 84
15 | 54
16 | 54
```

Comment: why not structure your sql so that the recordset has the correct order?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to sort the Query result using `ORDER BY id` [See the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sorting-rows.html)

Comment: that was the problem thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your array and then `ksort` it.

```
<?php

$array = [
 "id" => [15,13,16],
 "qty" => [54,84,54]
];

$combined = array_combine($array['id'], $array['qty']);
ksort($combined);
var_dump($combined);
```

Returns:

```
array(3) {
  [13]=>
  int(84)
  [15]=>
  int(54)
  [16]=>
  int(54)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make id as the key and qty as value to sort on id , then some reverse enginering  to get desired result.

```
<?php
$com = array_combine($proIdArr0["id"], $proIdArr0["qty"]);
ksort($com);
foreach($com as $k=>$v)
{
$proIdArr0["id"]=$k;
$proIdArr0["qty"]=$v;
}
```

But using order by in query is more preferable solution.